# Why can't I `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk`?

Tags: google-app-engine, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

I followed the instructions in this url,
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-debian-ubuntu
and when I typed the command

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
```

I got this errors:

```
E:Malformed line 5 in source list/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list(dist parse).
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I wrote the above command in virtualenv.
I cannot understand why this error happens.
All other step is completed, so I cannot understand why this happens.
How should I fix this?

Comment: `apt-get` will install at the system level; I'd suspect that calling it from within a virtualenv is going to lead to a messed up configuration.  Install the cloud sdk from a terminal that isn't running an active virtualenv.

Comment: This is a common error, check this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Answer (score 32):

this helped me:

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

after:

```
exec -l $SHELL
```

and finally:

```
gcloud init
```

it's an interactive installer from google, more info [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads)

Comment: it needs python :S   root/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh: 184: /root/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh: python: not found

Answer (score 1):

I followed the deb/ubuntu install instructions from here:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb

The commands basically boil down to the following:

`echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list`

`apt-get -y install apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg`

`curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -`

`apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install google-cloud-sdk kubectl`